# Bizarre Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting, sqldatatypes

When I select from a view, I get an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float.

Query:

```
select cast(myNumVal as float) myFloatVal 
from uvw_myView
```

When I execute it this, however, it works, no errors

```
select 
    cast(myNumVal as float) myFloatVal,  
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(myNumVal + 'e0') = 0 THEN myNumVal 
        ELSE null 
    END AS MyVarchar
from uvw_myView
```

The two queries are identical, with the exception of the additional column in the latter. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: Does you real query have a `where` clause?

Comment: Yes, it does have a simple where clause, e.g., where myCategory = 'x'

Comment: You have no guarantee whether or not the cast will happen before or after the where. In one plan you happen to be lucky in the other not.